# Can you create nodered nodes with other nodes?

Tags: node-red

I am building a Node-Red dashboard and have to differentiate the dashboard based on different users that login to it. Is it at all possible to create different nodes based on different users logged in? For example user 1 should see 3 temperature charts whilst user 2 should see 1 gauge. The information as to what they should see is stored in a database and I can already collect that just not build the different interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

No, node-red is single user, as is the dashboard.

If you want to discuss your requirements with the project, please jump on the mailing list linked from the bottom of nodered.org.